# Getting an error when I try to inflate my layout from this fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, layout-inflater

I have used this method already in my app and it worked fine. I'm doing exactly the same thing now but I'm getting an error message that says: Error inflating class android.view.View
I am using the same base XML layout as the previous screen. It has 2 Fragments. One up top that tells the user He/She is logged in and then my new Fragment (a form) below. However the one below seems to be the problem. Here is my base layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.bignerdranch.android.personaltrainer.CustomerListActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="304dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/logged_in_fragment_container"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        tools:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/list_fragment_container"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the top Fragement: don't know if you really need this one but here it is

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:id="@+id/container_for_loggedin_textview"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:padding="5dp"
             tools:context="com.bignerdranch.android.personaltrainer.LoggedInFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logged_in_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:text="You are logged in"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the Fragment I'm having an issue with when I try to inflate it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_new_customer_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/new_customer_title"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/new_customer_pic"
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="82dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_first_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="First Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_last_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Last Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_first_name"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_city"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="City"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_address"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_state"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:entries="@array/states"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_city"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.433"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tv_city"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_last_name"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.913"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_zip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="ZipCode"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_city"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:backgroundTint="@drawable/divider"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_zip"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cancel_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_customer_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_button"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/camera_button"/>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/camera_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_black_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:fabSize="auto"
        app:rippleColor="?android:attr/colorBackground"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/cancel_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/billing_info_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/billing_info_button"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_address"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Street Address"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_last_name"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the base Activity where I use the Fragment manager:

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.personaltrainer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;


public class NewCustomerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.logged_in_fragment_container);

        if (fragment == null){
            fragment = new LoggedInFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.logged_in_fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }

        // don't be confused by "list_fragment_container" it's the same container used for the recyclerview
        Fragment fragment2 = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.list_fragment_container);

        if (fragment2 == null){
            fragment2 = new NewCustomerFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.list_fragment_container, fragment2)
                    .commit();
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the Fragment that is throwing the error:

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.personaltrainer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bignerdranch.android.personaltrainer.model.Customer;

/**
 * Created by patricgekoski on 9/3/17.
 */

public class NewCustomerFragment extends Fragment {

    private Customer mCustomer;
    private Button mBillingInfoButton;
    private Button mCancelButton;
    private Button mAddButton;
    private FloatingActionButton mCameraButton;
    private ImageView mCustomerPic;
    private TextView mFirstName;
    private TextView mLastName;
    private TextView mAddress;
    private TextView mCity;
    private Spinner mState;
    private TextView mZip;

    public NewCustomerFragment(){
        // empty constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){
```

// !!!!!!! THIS NEXT LINE IS THROWING THE ERROR !!!!!!!!!!!

```
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_customer, parent, false);


        mBillingInfoButton.findViewById(R.id.billing_info_button);
        mCancelButton.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
        mAddButton.findViewById(R.id.add_customer_button);
        mCameraButton.findViewById(R.id.camera_button);
        mCustomerPic.findViewById(R.id.new_customer_pic);
        mFirstName.findViewById(R.id.tv_first_name);
        mLastName.findViewById(R.id.tv_last_name);
        mAddress.findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
        mCity.findViewById(R.id.tv_city);
        mState.findViewById(R.id.spinner_state);
        mZip.findViewById(R.id.tv_zip);

        return view;

    }
}
```

Lastly here is my stack trace: At least part of it

```
09-03 10:25:50.996 29649-29649/com.bignerdranch.android.personaltrainer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                          Process: com.bignerdranch.android.personaltrainer, PID: 29649
                                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bignerdranch.android.personaltrainer/com.bignerdranch.android.personaltrainer.NewCustomerActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #112: Binary XML file line #112: Error inflating class android.view.View
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #112: Binary XML file line #112: Error inflating class android.view.View
                                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                              at com.bignerdranch.android.personaltrainer.NewCustomerFragment.onCreateView(NewCustomerFragment.java:43)
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2239)
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1332)
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1574)
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1641)
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:794)
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2200)
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2153)
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2063)
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:554)
                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
                                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
                                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #112: Error inflating class android.view.View
                                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:677)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
                                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
                                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                              at com.bignerdranch.android.personaltrainer.NewCustomerFragment.onCreateView(NewCustomerFragment.java:43) 
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2239) 
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1332) 
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1574) 
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1641) 
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:794) 
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415) 
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2200) 
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2153) 
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2063) 
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388) 
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:554) 
                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177) 
                                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237) 
                                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253) 
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This is a very subtle mistake. I was trying to use the "backgroundTint" attribute in my layout but that was introduced at a higher level than my minimum API of 19.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out all of the codes inside that fragment, beginning from inflate to findView. If problem still persist, the problem might occur from the NumbersActivity as suggested by the stack trace, try commenting out part that invokes NumbersFragment for more hints. Hope that leads you toward the solution.